# I want to show all image sin my application,its value is coming in logcat but not on screen,what should i do?

Tags: android

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    int mCurrentPage;
    Context c;
    GridView mListView;
    String id, cat;
    String strUrl;
    TextView tvtitle;
    TextView tv_id, tv_rating, tv_url;
    public static String img_url, img_rating, img_id, img_name;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle data = getArguments();
        mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = null;
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.starters, container, false);
        tv_id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id);
        tv_rating = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf);
        tv_url = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url);
        cat = Category.Main_Cat;
        Log.i("Logcat Cat1", cat);
        switch (mCurrentPage) {
        case 1:
            Log.v("MyFragment Heap", "Max Mem in MB:" + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024));
            // strUrl =
            // "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/get_json.php?cat="+cat+"&subcat=1";
            strUrl = " http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?category=BollyWood%20&sub_category=top";
            downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
            mListView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), Starter_info.class);
                    img_id = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id)).getText().toString();
                    img_rating = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf)).getText().toString();
                    img_url = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url)).getText().toString();
                    img_name = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename)).getText().toString();
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            // strUrl =
            // "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/get_json.php?cat="+cat+"&subcat=1";
            strUrl = " http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?category=BollyWood%20&sub_category=top";
            downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
            Log.v("Splash Heap", "Max Mem in MB:" + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024));
            mListView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), Starter_info.class);
                    img_id = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id)).getText().toString();
                    img_rating = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf)).getText().toString();
                    img_url = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url)).getText().toString();
                    img_name = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename)).getText().toString();
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            Log.i("Cat IS", Category.Main_Cat);
            // strUrl =
            // "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/get_json.php?cat="+cat+"&subcat=1";
            strUrl = " http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?  category=BollyWood%20&sub_category=top";
            downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
            Log.v("Splash Heap", "Max Mem in MB:" + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024));
            mListView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), Starter_info.class);
                    img_id = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id)).getText().toString();
                    img_rating = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf)).getText().toString();
                    img_url = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url)).getText().toString();
                    img_name = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename)).getText().toString();
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
            break;
        }
        return v;
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();
            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            data = sb.toString();
            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
        }

        return data;
    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        String data = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();
            listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter> {
        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
                StarterParser countryJsonParser = new StarterParser();
                countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("JSON Exception1", e.toString());
            }
            StarterParser countryJsonParser = new StarterParser();
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;
            try {
                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            String[] from = { "poster", "year", "duration", "id", "title" };
            int[] to = { R.id.iv_flag, R.id.tv_starter_hide_url, R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf, R.id.tv_starter_hide_id, R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename };
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);

            return adapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
                ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

                HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put("flag_path", imgUrl);
                hm.put("position", i);
                imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>> {

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

            InputStream iStream = null;
            String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
            int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(imgUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                // Getting Caching directory
                File cacheDirectory = getActivity().getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_" + position + ".png");

                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

                // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOutStream);

                // Flush the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.flush();

                // Close the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.close();

                // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position
                // in the listview
                HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                hmBitmap.put("flag", tmpFile.getPath());

                // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                hmBitmap.put("position", position);

                // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and
                // position
                return hmBitmap;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
            // Getting the path to the downloaded image
            String path = (String) result.get("flag");

            // Getting the position of the downloaded image
            int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

            // Getting adapter of the listview
            SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) mListView.getAdapter();

            // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the
            // listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);

            // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
            hm.put("flag", path);

            // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

in my application i am getting threadpool execption when i am running it,my values are displaying in logcat but not showing on screen,due to rejetcted execution exeception,waht should i do..,i have try this[enter link description here](http://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

If your build target is set to API Level 11 or higher you may use below code while executing tasks.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
else {
  myTask.execute();
}
```

[Read more](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html)